# can't get python to do simple increment in for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, increment

I'm just starting with Python (with a good amount of VBA under my belt) so I'm playing around with some simple syntax.

I've written this simple for-loop but the output seems wrong.  I can't get the variable 'c' to increment.

Here is my code:

```
class Card:
    def county(self):
        for n in range(0,13):
            c = 0
            c = c + 1
            print c
    pick_card = Card()
    print pick_card.county()
```

and the output is just '1' printed 13 times followed by "None"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should move `c = 0` outside the loop ;).  Also, python supports `+=` like in C.  so you could do `c += 1` instead of `c = c + 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time through the loop, you're setting `c` to `0`, then adding `1`, making it 1.

Also, your last line is printing the return value from your function, which doesn't return anything (hence the "None")

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning it 0 first and then increment it by 1. Thus it's always 1.
Try using the following:

```
class Card:
    def county(self):
        c = 0
        for n in range(0,13):
            c += 1
            print c
    pick_card = Card()
    print pick_card.county()
```

Comment: Thanks.  Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Uh-oh -- IndentationFault ...  (sorry, some reason I thought that was funny because it sounds like SegmentationFault).

Comment: with the way SO determines code (by indenting) and the importance of indenting python code -- these things are bound to happen on a reasonably short timescale.